# Creating bar plot with negative and positive value , using R

Tags: r, bar-chart, visualization

I would like to create a bar plot with negative and positive values, shown as below (first image), where there is a line 0 at the middle. However, the bar plot that I have created has bars that all appear in an upright position (second image).

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

May I know how to make my bar plot (Image 2) to be like the bar plot in Image 1?

My code:

```
ggplot(fuel_trend, aes(fuel_type, changes)) + geom_col(position = "identity")
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Greetings! It is generally good practice to share a reproducible version of your data so others can help. Can you run `dput(fuel_trend)` and paste the output into your question? That may help others assist you faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried recreating your data since you didn't provide any in your question. If your data is coded as numeric, this shouldn't be a problem, as shown below.

```
#### Load Tidyverse ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Recreate Data ####
fuel_type <- c("DIESEL",
          "DIESEL/ELECTRIC",
          "LPG",
          "PETROL",
          "PETROL/ELECTRIC")

changes <- c(-1097.82,
             92.96,
             59.35,
             -55.15,
             88.04)

df <- data.frame(fuel_type,
                 changes)

#### Plot ####
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=fuel_type,
             y=changes))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

However, your `changes` variable may be coded wrong. Here I have showed the same plot, but coded the data as a factor instead. This can also be the case if your variable is coded as a character.

```
#### Coded as Factor ####
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=fuel_type,
             y=factor(changes)))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

To fix this, either change the class of the data in the data frame (here I have saved it as `df2`:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(changes = as.numeric(changes))
```

...or plot it as numeric with `as.numeric` like so with the original `df` data frame:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=fuel_type,
             y=as.numeric(changes)))+
  geom_col()
```

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for the help. Both codes work. :)

Comment: Great! If you felt my answer solved your problem, please select the check mark next to my answer (you may need to wait some time in order to do so).